# PDOStatement->execute() User->userRegistration(Array)

Tags: php

```
<?php

include "session.php";
include "Database.php";

class User{

    private $db; 
    public function __construct(){
        $this->db = new Database();
    }

    public function userRegistration($data){
        $name  = $data['name'];
        $usnm  = $data['usnm'];
        $email = $data['email'];
        $pass  = md5($data['pass']);

        $chk_email = $this->emailcheck($email);

        if($name == "" OR $usnm == "" OR $email == "" OR $pass == ""){
                $msg = "<div class='alert alert-denger'><strong>Error !</strong>Field must not be empty</div>";

                return $msg;
        }
        if(strlen($usnm) < 3){
            $msg = "<div class='alert alert-denger'>username too short!</div>";

                return $msg;
        }
        elseif(preg_match('/[^a-z0-9_-]+/i' ,$usnm)){

            $msg = "<div class='alert alert-denger'>Username must in alphanumeric!</div>";

                return $msg;
        }
        if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false){
            $msg = "<div class='alert alert-denger'>Invalid Email Id!</div>";

                return $msg;
        }
        if($chk_email == true){
            $msg = "<div class='alert alert-denger'>Email Id Already Exist!</div>";

                return $msg;
        }
        $sql = "insert into register (name,user_name,email_id,password) values (:name, :username, :email, :password)";
        $query = $this->db->pdo->prepare($sql);
        $query->bindValue(':name',$name);
        $query->bindValue(':user_name',$usnm);
        $query->bindValue(':email_id',$email);
        $query->bindValue(':password',$pass);
        $result = $query->execute();
        if($result){

            $msg = "<div class='alert alert-success'><strong>Success</strong>You have been Registered</div>";

                return $msg;
        }else{

            $msg = "<div class='alert alert-denger'><strong>Error !</strong>Sorry, there has been problem inserting your details!</div>";

                return $msg;

        }
    }
    public function emailcheck($email){
        $sql = "select email_id from register email_id = :email";
        $query = $this->db->pdo->prepare($sql);
        $query->bindparam(':email_id', $email);
        $query->execute();
        if($query->rowCount() > 0){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}

?>
```

and i got this error

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined'
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\lib\user.php:71 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\test\lib\user.php(71): PDOStatement->execute() #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\test\lib\user.php(19):
>   User->emailcheck('jpjadeja24@gmai...') #2
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\test\register.php(7): User->userRegistration(Array) #3
>   {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\lib\user.php on line 71

Comment: If you cannot be bothered to format the code so its readable. **Why shoudl we bother trying to help

Comment: This should fail at the prepare call already, because `select email_id from register email_id = :email` is obviously not a valid SQL statement, that is missing the WHERE keyword.

Answer (score 1):

The parameter names used in the `bindValue()` call have to match those used in the query

So

```
    $sql = "insert into register 
                    (name,user_name,email_id,password) 
             values (:name, :username, :email, :password)";
    $query = $this->db->pdo->prepare($sql);
    $query->bindValue(':name',$name);
    $query->bindValue(':user_name',$usnm);

    // The FIX
    //$query->bindValue(':email_id',$email);
    $query->bindValue(':email',$email);

    $query->bindValue(':password',$pass);
    $result = $query->execute();
```

Alternatively, change the query param

```
    $sql = "insert into register 
                    (name,user_name,email_id,password) 
             values (:name, :username, :email_id, :password)";
    //                                 ^^^^^^^^^

    $query = $this->db->pdo->prepare($sql);
    $query->bindValue(':name',$name);
    $query->bindValue(':user_name',$usnm);
    $query->bindValue(':email_id',$email);
    $query->bindValue(':password',$pass);
    $result = $query->execute();
```

> Also this will be your next problem, a missing WHERE and you have made the same mistake with the binding

```
public function emailcheck($email){
    $sql = "select email_id from register WHERE email_id = :email";
    //                                    ^^^^^
    $query = $this->db->pdo->prepare($sql);

    // AND THE SAME FIX REQUIRED HERE

    //$query->bindparam(':email_id', $email);
    $query->bindValue(':email',$email);
    $query->execute();
```

Comment: thank u nut now same error in line no #53

Comment: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined' in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\lib\user.php:53 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\test\lib\user.php(53): PDOStatement->execute() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\test\register.php(7): User->userRegistration(Array) #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\lib\user.php on line 53

Comment: See amended answer, I missed that one, but you really should have been able to work that out _for yourself_ as its the exact same issue as already mentioned

Answer (score 1):

My be because of the typo while assigning the values to the parameters.
This should work. Modify your query on line #47

```
$sql = "insert into register (name,user_name,email_id,password) values (:name, :user_name, :email_id, :password)";
```

Comment: i try but not working, same error occured

Comment: Also you need to change it to `email_id` on line #69.

Comment: but now error occured in this code


$sql = "insert into register (name,user_name,email,password) values (:name, :username, :email, :password)";
        $query = $this->db->pdo->prepare($sql);
        $query->bindValue(':name',$name);
        $query->bindValue(':user_name',$usnm);
        $query->bindValue(':email',$email);
        $query->bindValue(':password',$pass);
        $result = $query->execute();

Comment: Try printing the sql error. `print_r($query->errorInfo());`

Comment: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined'                                                                                                                                                                      












print this error

Comment: Are you sure `(name,user_name,email_id,password)` are correct ? I mean, you have the same columns(names) in your `table`

Comment: yes sir ji, its my table column name